# Issue with an "is_prime" python function on Sublime Text

Tags: python, primes, sublimetext3

I am trying to run the following simple code:

```
import math
def is_prime(N):
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(N))):
        if (N % i == 0) :
            print(str(N) + " is not prime")
            return False 
    print(str(N) + " is prime")
    return True
```

The goal is to determine whether or not a number is prime (pretty simple). However, I can't get this code to work. I have managed to pinpoint the issue around the `int(math.sqrt(N))` instructions, but I don't understand why it won't work, as running `int(math.sqrt(134))` for example works fine for me. Is there anything wrong I can't see in this code?

I have also come to question the compiler's viability. I am using Sublime Text 3 with the default Python Builder. Maybe there is something I am doing that is specifically wrong on Sublime Text?

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention the issue. When I run `is_prime(8)` for instance, it returns `8 is prime`. But it doesn't display any error at all. However, it should be noted that running `is_prime(134)` prints `134 is not prime` as expected. I could try a `for` loop if anyone wants.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? It produces incorrect results? It throws an error?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't precise enough: it produces incorrect results (8 becomes a prime number) but absolutely no error.

Comment: `int(math.sqrt(8)) == 2`. Of course it outputs that it's prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import math
def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n))+1):
        if n%i == 0 :
            return False 
    return True
```

`range()` stops before it actually gets to the second number. In this case, you want to test that number as well, so you want to round down, and then add one.

---

More efficient version (`x10 - x1000` speed improvement):

```
def memoise(func):
    memory = {}
    def wrapper(n):
        if n in memory:
            return memory[n]
        ret = func(n)
        memory[n] = ret
        return ret
    return wrapper

@memoise
def is_prime(n):
    if n <= 3:
        return n > 1
    if not n%2 or not n%3:
        return False

    for i in range(5, int(n**0.5)+1, 6):
        if not n%i or not n%(i+2):
            return False
    return True
```

---

Playing in the interpreter:

```
>>> math.sqrt(8)
2.8284271247461903
>>> int(math.sqrt(8)) + 1
3
>>> for i in range(2, 2):
        print(i)

>>> for i in range(2, 3):
        print(i)

2
```

Comment: Hum… using your solution (with int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(N))) instead of just math.ceil(math.sqrt(N))) works fine. At least for smaller numbers. Is it because sqrt(8) = 2.828427125 is too small?

Comment: @LaX No, it's because you want to test all integers up to `math.sqrt(N)`. So you should round down the result, then add `1` to account for `range()` not including the last number.

Comment: Oh... right. Thanks! Having tried ridiculously complex function to test out `int(…)`, I feel a bit… dumb

Comment: @LaX Also, you know `0` and `1` aren't prime, right?

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote some of the lines in your program making it a little bit more efficient.
Your for loop iterates over all numbers up to the root of N. If you start by checking if the number % 2 == 0, you can then exclude all even numbers and only check the odd numbers 3, 5, 7, ....

```
import math
def is_prime(N):
    if(N == 2):
        print(str(N) + " is a prime")
        return True
    if((N % 2 == 0)or(N == 1)):
        print(str(N) + " is not prime")
        return False
    for i in range(3,int(math.sqrt(N))+1,2):
        if(N % i == 0):
            print(str(N) + " is not prime")
            return False
    print(str(N) + " is prime")
    return True
```

Comment: I thought about that. But shouldn't you use `return(N == 2)` instead of `return False` in the `% 2` test? Because `2` would return as a non-prime number.

Comment: You are right! I ignored the case of N = 2  (edited the answer).

Comment: @LaX I have added a more efficient version to my answer as well.

Comment: @Scorpion_God for i in range(5, int(n**0.5)+1, 6):
     if not n%i or not n%(i+2):

the reason that you have 6 in the += field is because you want to avoid the numbers that are multiples of 3, right?